# Angular component styleguide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angular-js-styleguide-snippets` for `Atom`, which, when I type `ngcomponent` on my editor, expands into the following structure:

```
( function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'arroyo' )
        .component( 'intro', component );

    /* @ngInject */
    function component() {
        var settings = {
            template: '<h1>test</h1>',
            controller: Controller,
        };

        return settings;
    }

    Controller.$inject = [];

    /* @ngInject */
    function Controller() {

    }
} )();
```

However, using the code above does not seem to be working. While there are no console errors, the component itself (`<intro></intro>`) does not render anything. After some fiddling around I found out that using the code below works as expected:

```
( function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'arroyo' )
        .component( 'intro', {
            template: '<h1>test</h1>'
        } );
} )();
```

What's wrong with the first snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You must call the function component like so:

```
angular
    .module( 'arroyo' )
    .component( 'intro', component());
```

The new component method actually takes an object in which you give the settings, by calling the function you return that object.

Check out the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for more info.